# Android application not working on different Android versions

Tags: android, android-version

I have developed a Android application with `targetSdkVersion="15"` . When I run this application on Android 4.0.3 it's working fine. but When i was try this on Android 2.3.3 it shows the error. so, now I would like to know, how can we find the versioning problem automatically and how can we omit the versioning problems while we develop. kindly some one guide me in this. thanks in advance.

This one is stack trace in my logcat.

```
10-04 08:36:00.731: W/dalvikvm(413): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception    (group=0x40015560)
10-04 08:36:00.742: E/AndroidRuntime(413): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-04 08:36:00.742: E/AndroidRuntime(413): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:     com.net.elderlyhealth.MainActivityMainpage$PagerAdapter
10-04 08:36:00.742: E/AndroidRuntime(413):  at  com.net.elderlyhealth.MainActivityMainpage.onCreate(MainActivityMainpage.java:62)
10-04 08:36:00.742: E/AndroidRuntime(413):  at  android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
10-04 08:36:00.742: E/AndroidRuntime(413):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
10-04 08:36:00.742: E/AndroidRuntime(413):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
10-04 08:36:00.742: E/AndroidRuntime(413):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
10-04 08:36:00.742: E/AndroidRuntime(413):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
10-04 08:36:00.742: E/AndroidRuntime(413):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-04 08:36:00.742: E/AndroidRuntime(413):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
10-04 08:36:00.742: E/AndroidRuntime(413):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
10-04 08:36:00.742: E/AndroidRuntime(413):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-04 08:36:00.742: E/AndroidRuntime(413):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
10-04 08:36:00.742: E/AndroidRuntime(413):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
10-04 08:36:00.742: E/AndroidRuntime(413):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
10-04 08:36:00.742: E/AndroidRuntime(413):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: What about your android:minSdkVersion?

Comment: @userIsAMonkey I am using android:minSdkVersion="7"

Comment: "Android application not working"... "the error"... "versioning problems"... none of these are things that will help us solve your issue. Be specific, give logs, real, hard data, pertinent code, the manifest if necessary... etc.

Comment: @userIsAMonkey Actually I have solved the error. but here my question is , how to find the versioning problem or how to omit the versioning problems when we do coding. because these tips maybe helpful for me for upcoming tasks.

Comment: @Eric Thanks for your reply. actually here I asked some guidance for omit versioning problem while we do coding.

Comment: I did the research for you. Check this out http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/06/noclassdeffounderror-exception-in.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The android LINT checks go some way towards this, but honestly beyond that the best way is to run the app on a device with your minimum SDK version on a regular basis.

Comment: yes you are correct.. it's gives me clear idea on this. thanks.

Comment: Also if you conditionally load code for an API level above your minimum (like this: http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2010/07/how-to-have-your-cupcake-and-eat-it-too.html) it's worth looking at using the @TargetApi annotation to identify it.

Answer (score 2):

Could you provide the stacktrace of the error? So that at least we could get some idea on how we could help you?

With regards to omitting the version problem, might as well try adding the line

```
android:minSdkVersion="8"
```

in your manifest file right before

```
targetSdkVersion="15"
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, the answer is simple.

The android SDK makes the targeted API available to your project. If you use an API which is not available in lower versions then you will get the error.

Workaround

1. check the availability of an API on the docs before using it
2. use reflection and cater for cases when the API is not available. The behaviour of your app will not be consistent across all the devices.
3. You should actually target your project to the minimum API.